# how do I apply jquery effects to generated HTML that is inserted with getElementById?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

this doesnt seem to work:

```
    <script>
    window.onload = function()   
    {    
        var div = '<div id="accordion">';
        div += '<div>';
          div += '<h3>section1</h3>';
          div += '<p>text 1</p>';
          div += '</div>';
        div += '<div>';
          div += '<h3>section2</h3>';
          div += '<p>text 2</p>';
        div += '</div>';
        div += '</div>';

        document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = div;
    }
    </script>
```

rest of html with links to jquery libs is left out of this code

Comment: First, why don't you just convert it over to jQuery instead of mixing the two?

Comment: After adding the HTML, you can access it with jQuery by calling `$('#accordion')`.

Comment: what effect you want to apply ?

Comment: That code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jcyL8/

Comment: Yeah I know but I need to use this in a lesson example

Comment: concentenating a string is'nt really a very good way to create DOM elements.

Comment: The code is perfectly put in a div with id "list" but it won't get the jquery effect although I have a jquery script part in my html page that says 
        $(function() {
         $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
          heightStyle: "content"
         });
        });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use jqueryui accordion, you html code it's wrong, acording [jqueryUi](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) doc, you must try this :

```
function initAccordion (){
    $(function() { 
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ heightStyle: "content" }); 
    });
}

window.onload = function()   
{    
    var div = '<div id="accordion">';
    div += '<h3>section1</h3><div>';
    div += '<p>text 1</p>';
    div += '</div>';
    div += '<h3>section2</h3><div>';
    div += '<p>text 2</p>';
    div += '</div>';
    div += '</div>';

    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = div;
    //init jquery accordion
    initAccordion();    
 }
```

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/edbNu/)

Comment: @ArjoPost This solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is to do some sort of animation on the new content, you can do it like this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function()   
{    
    var div = '<div id="accordion" style="display: none;">';
    div += '<div>';
      div += '<h3>section1</h3>';
      div += '<p>text 1</p>';
      div += '</div>';
    div += '<div>';
      div += '<h3>section2</h3>';
      div += '<p>text 2</p>';
    div += '</div>';
    div += '</div>';

    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = div;
    $("#accordion").fadeIn(2000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert this:

```
window.onload = function()   
{    
    var div = '<div id="accordion">';
    div += '<div>';
      div += '<h3>section1</h3>';
      div += '<p>text 1</p>';
      div += '</div>';
    div += '<div>';
      div += '<h3>section2</h3>';
      div += '<p>text 2</p>';
    div += '</div>';
    div += '</div>';

    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = div;
}
```

Into this:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    var div = '<div id="accordion">';
        div += '<div>';
        div += '<h3>section1</h3>';
        div += '<p>text 1</p>';
        div += '</div>';
        div += '<div>';
        div += '<h3>section2</h3>';
        div += '<p>text 2</p>';
        div += '</div>';
        div += '</div>';

    $('#list')
            .html(div)
            .promise()
            .done(function(){    
                $('#accordion').animate({opacity:0.2},1000);
            });
});
```

Or whatever animation you want to do. The `.promise()` basically creates a waiter for the object until all actions are complete and `.done(function(){})` attaches a successful callback to it. Pretty nifty, you can do this for any element now.

[.promise() info here](http://api.jquery.com/promise/), [.done() info here](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

As a side note, you really should think about the appending you're doing. Can this be in the HTML, set to `display:none`, and then SHOWN on load based on something specific? Just something to consider.

**EDIT**: new approach, [tested here with basic animation](http://jsfiddle.net/B4M8C/). Works.

Comment: hi this gives the same result as I had; the div is filled with data but there is no accordion effect upon the div with id list (which is the div that is being populated); does it have something to do with the location of the jquery libraries in the html? I put all the scripts and links above your code in the head

Comment: alright modded my answer to try something a little different, using the new `.promise().done(function(){})` capabilities jQuery 1.9 offers. it works with normal animation, as shown in the jsFiddle link i provided. if you dont see the animation the first time it loads, run it again. you'll see that the animation is properly applied to the previously-unreachable `#accordion` element.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, there's a div with an ID of accordion which contains two divs.  Each of these two divs have a header tag as as well as a paragraph tag.  Both of the header tags and both of the paragraph tags contain copy.

I can't think of a super-neat way to do this as a lot of elements are being created on the fly.  I do think that creating all the stuff off-DOM with createElement(), arranging it with appendChild() and then loading it all via a document fragment is a good way to go as it's significantly better from a performance standpoint. Paul Irish goes into great detail about all this [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=q_O9_C2ZjoA).

```
  $(function(){
    // on the page already...just targeting it with a variable
    var onPageEl = document.getElementById('list');

    // created off-DOM...we'll load our stuff here before loading it onto the page
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    // create elements
    var accordion = document.createElement('div');
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    var header1 = document.createElement('h3');
    var somePara1 = document.createElement('p');
    var div2 = document.createElement('div');
    var header2 = document.createElement('h3');
    var somePara2 = document.createElement('p');

    // use jQuery to give our containing element an ID of 'accordion'
    $(accordion).attr('id', 'accordion');

    // arrange the first bulk of div code
    accordion.appendChild(div1);
    div1.appendChild(header1);
    div1.appendChild(somePara1);
    header1.innerHTML = "section1";
    somePara1.innerHTML = "text1";

    // arrange the second bulk of div code
    accordion.appendChild(div2);
    div2.appendChild(header2);
    div2.appendChild(somePara2);
    header2.innerHTML = "section2";
    somePara2.innerHTML = "text2";

    // Load both bulks of content into the document fragment
    frag.appendChild(div1);
    frag.appendChild(div2);

    // Load the document fragment onto 'list' which is already on the page
    onPageEl.appendChild(frag);
  });
```

Since there are some things that are being created twice, a function could be used to create stuff but that may create a performance issue.

Just my $.02...